# VC++ connection to mysql about Connection and Sql String

Tags: mysql, visual-c++

I have seen some sample code to write a VC++ connection to mysql function. The function is work.

```
public: String^ url = "localhost";
public: String^ dbName = "dbtest";
public: String^ userName = "root";
public: String^ password = "password";
public: String^ port = "3306";

String^ MysqlUrl = L"datasource=" + url + ";port=" + port + ";username=" + userName + ";password=" + password;
SelectStr = L"SELECT * FROM " + dbName + ".dbtable0001 WHERE id='" + select_id_var + "';";
MySqlConnection^ MysqlConn = gcnew MySqlConnection(MysqlUrl);
MySqlCommand^ MysqlCmd = gcnew MySqlCommand(SelectStr, MysqlConn);
```

But I want the "dbName" is in the "MysqlUrl", not in the "SelectStr". How to do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems it has nothing to do with C++ at all. Have you tried the "database" parameter from [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connecting-open.html)?:

```
String^ MysqlUrl = L"datasource=" + url + 
    ";port=" + port + 
    ";username=" + userName + 
    ";password=" + password + 
    ";database=" + dbName;
```